# How to take IP addresses from a string list and use them as IP.Net.IPAddress

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a list of IP addresses in a MySQL database. I have added those IP addresses to a string list.

```
public void GetServerList()
        {
            //Create SqlConnection
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(cs);

            con.Open();

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from servers", con);

            //Create a data reader and Execute the command
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //Read the data and store them in the list
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                AAServerAddressList.Add(dataReader["Server_IP"] + "");

                for (int i = 0; i < AAServerAddressList.Count; i++)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(AAServerAddressList[i]);
                    AAServerAddress = IPAddress.Parse(AAServerAddressList[i]); // AAserverAddress & AAServerAddressList defined in public partial class Form1 : Form
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

i want to know how to use this list to replace this:

```
IPAddress AAServerAddress = IPAddress.Parse("173.234.31.212");
```

Which is used here:

```
private void Search(int secondsToReceive)
        {
            try
            {
                // Some more reading material on datagrams:
                // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datagram
                this.searchSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

                // Allow the usage of broadcast.
                this.searchSock.EnableBroadcast = true;

                // Set the ReceiveTimeout in seconds!
                // Remember, the intervals are normally in milliseconds, so you must multiply everything by
                // 1000 in order to get seconds!
                this.searchSock.ReceiveTimeout = secondsToReceive * 1000;

                // Set DontFragment to true. We won't be sending packets larger than the maximum allowed, but it's the
                // peace of mind that counts. Read about DontFragment on the MSDN.
                this.searchSock.DontFragment = true;

                // Create an IPEndPoint object to hold our target. We are sending to the Broadcast address which means
                // all machines on this network listening on the port specified by argument #2 will get a copy of
                // this packet.
                IPEndPoint target = new IPEndPoint(AAServerAddress, AAPort);

                // We will be sending a single packet. This is highly inaccurate and I wouldn't be caught doing this in a
                // major application, but this is a basics tutorial.
                // Make a call to SendTo. This is a special kind of function as it requires no confirmation of the remote
                // host even being alive. You can use SendTo on an application that isn't listening, the packet will send
                // but you will not get a reply.
                this.searchSock.SendTo(statusPacket, (EndPoint)target);

                shouldReceive = true;

                while (shouldReceive)
                {
                    // Create a byte array of length 2000 to hold the information sent back to us.
                    byte[] reply = new byte[2000];

                    // Create a new EndPoint to hold the network information of the sender.
                    EndPoint remote = ((EndPoint)new IPEndPoint(AAServerAddress, 0));

                    // This call receives a packet from a remote host. This is a blocking call. Meaning the thread
                    // will hang on this statement until we receive x amount. The amount received will be stored in 'i', this
                    // is an important variable (I'll explain why later.)
                    int i = searchSock.ReceiveFrom(reply, ref remote);

                    ProcessPacket(reply, i, remote);
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                /*
                // Our search has timed out or we have clicked the "Stop" button.
                // Just in case it was a timeout.
                btnSearch.Text = "Search";
                lblStatus.Text = "Idle...";
                shouldReceive = false;
                searchSock.Close();

                // Join the thread this method ran on with our UI thread.
                searchThread.Join(1000);*/
                MessageBox.Show("Query Timed out or Stopped!");
            }
        }
```

The main goal i am trying to reach is to query all the IP addresses in that list instead of just querying one at a time, i originally had AAServerAddress set to a specific IP like this:

```
IPAddress AAServerAddress = IPAddress.Parse("173.234.31.212");
```

Currently the program only queries one IP address from the list.

Comment: What specific problem are you having, what have you tried, and what about your attempts wasn’t successful?

Comment: Well i know how to set the connection string i have a launcher i'm writing for America's Army 2.8.5 it can check the MySQL server to see if the username and e-mail are already registered it, It can also check to make sure the username and password are correct.

This project is separate until i get it working the way i want, the thing is i don't really know where to start as far as getting the data into a list or array so that i can use it with this code:
https://pastebin.com/9XU2DgZe

Comment: can this be reopened? , i cant seem to get the post to allow my code or link a pasebin.com link in the main post, i just need info on how to take the info from the database and put it in a list so that i can use it in place of System.Net.IPAddress

Comment: Type (or better, copy) the code into the question. (Use the `edit` button to edit the question.) Then select the code you just typed and type ctl-K. Or use the edit box button that looks like this: `{}`. If you're using the mobile interface, you need to indent every line with four spaces. I know, it's a pain. Try to find a non-mobile device.

Comment: Ok thanks i am now able to add my code, i have got everything into a list and edited my question, if it could be reopened that would be awesome.

Comment: This seems like to much (mostly-irrelevant) code after the edit, but at least it's probably answerable now. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a couple solutions to my question, i will post the better solution here.

So in stead of using a list i decided to use a DataTable:

```
public DataTable GetServerListdt()
        {
            //Create SqlConnection
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(cs);

            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from serversstest", con);
            //MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //sda.Fill(dt);
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            con.Close();
            return dt;
        }
```

Then i moved and modified the code for querying servers from my Search method to a new method  named QueryServer:

```
private void QueryServer(IPAddress IP, int Port)
    {
        Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\\100 * 1024\\");

        udpClient.Connect(IP, Port);

        udpClient.Client.EnableBroadcast = true;

        // Set DontFragment to true. We won't be sending packets larger than the maximum allowed, but it's the
        // peace of mind that counts. Read about DontFragment on the MSDN.
        udpClient.Client.DontFragment = true;

        // Create an IPEndPoint object to hold our target. We are sending to the Broadcast address which means
        // all machines on this network listening on the port specified by argument #2 will get a copy of
        // this packet.
        IPEndPoint target = new IPEndPoint(IP, Port);

        // We will be sending a single packet. This is highly inaccurate and I wouldn't be caught doing this in a
        // major application, but this is a basics tutorial.
        // Make a call to SendTo. This is a special kind of function as it requires no confirmation of the remote
        // host even being alive. You can use SendTo on an application that isn't listening, the packet will send
        // but you will not get a reply.
        udpClient.Client.SendTo(sendBytes, (EndPoint)target);

        byte[] reply = new byte[2000];

        // Create a new EndPoint to hold the network information of the sender.
        EndPoint remote = ((EndPoint)new IPEndPoint(IP, Port));

        int i = udpClient.Client.ReceiveFrom(reply, ref remote);

        ProcessPacket(reply, i, remote);
    }
```

Then i called my QueryServer method from my Search method:

```
private void Search(int secondsToReceive)
        {
            DataTable dt = GetServerListdt();

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                string ServerName = row["Server_Name"].ToString();
                IPAddress ServerIP = IPAddress.Parse(row["Server_IP"].ToString());
                int ServerPort = int.Parse(row["Server_Port"].ToString());
                int ServerQueryPort = int.Parse(row["Server_QueryPort"].ToString());

                QueryServer(ServerIP, ServerQueryPort);
            }
        }
```

Weather using a list or a DataTable the solution was the same.

1.) Put the code that queries the server in its own method.

2.) Use a foreach loop to call the query method for every IP/Port in a list or datatable and add it to the listview